# Problem in Binding a DependencyProperty into another one at XAML

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, dependency-properties, bind

OK,
I have a data template for items:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SmallDayEventItemTemplate">
        <Border ...>
            <Grid ...>

                <TextBlock ...
                        Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>

                <my:SmallPlayer ...
                        PlayerSource="{Binding Path=MediaSource}">
                </my:SmallPlayer>
             </Grid>
        </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Also i have a `UserControl` named `SmallPlayer`.
In SmallPlayer.xaml.cs:

```
 public Uri PlayerSource
        {
            get { return (Uri)GetValue(PlayerSourceProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(PlayerSourceProperty, value);
                //player.Open(value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PlayerSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlayerSource", typeof(Uri), typeof(SmallPlayer));
```

So when i feed `MediaSource` of an item inside owner window code, `item`'s `set` accessor gets called but, `SmallPlayer`'s `PlayerSource`'s `set` accessor never gets called! This is while `TextBlock` which is bind to `Title` property acts as expected!

```
Uri uri = null;
if (Uri.TryCreate(mediaName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri))
       item.MediaSource = uri;
```

It make me confuse! What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLR wrapper for a dependency property is never guaranteed to be called, so should never contain any extraneous logic. If you need extra logic when the dependency property is changed, use [dependency property metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752375.aspx). And specifically, the property changed callback.

Comment: And to be more accurate - use property changed callback